# Awesome WM current layout

Tags: awesome-wm

I'm wanna to write polybar module that displaying awesome current screen layout.
Does awesome have function to return current screen layout with string or image?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can use the `mouse.screen.selected_tag.layout.name` to get the name. This can be coupled with `awesome-client` like this:

```
awesome-client 'return mouse.screen.selected_tag.layout.name'
```

You can get the client/window geometry using `mouse.screen.selected_tag:clients()`. An image can be created using the Cairo API too. But at that point, you might want to reconsider using polybar and switch to the built-in `awful.wibar` module. Getting data in and out just for the sake of keeping polybar will end up being harder and more complex than porting a polybar design to wibar.